# Error when trying to replace an UNC path by a string

Tags: c#

Sorry for some maybe very basic questions. I simply wanted to replace the UNC path by a string. These lines with the UNC path for a C++ connection perfectly works:

```
[DllImport(C:\\Users\\SJ\\Documents\\VS2015\\Projects\\P_01\\Debug\\EV_01.dll",
EntryPoint = "DDentry", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern void DDentry
(
   [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.SafeArray, SafeArraySubType = VarEnum.VT_BSTR)]
    string[,] pArrayStr
);
```

Replacing the UNC path by a string gives an error "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property"

```
string UNCpath = @"C:\\Users\\SJ\\Documents\\VS2015\\Projects\\P_01\\Debug\\EV_01.dll";

[DllImport(UNCpath,
EntryPoint = "DDentry", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern void DDentry
(
   [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.SafeArray, SafeArraySubType = VarEnum.VT_BSTR)]
    string[,] pArrayStr
);
```

Many thank for your ideas ..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing a custom attribute with a variable value as a parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13125046/passing-a-custom-attribute-with-a-variable-value-as-a-parameter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot pass the instance value `UNCPath` into an attribute like that.  It would need to be a constant.  Also, if you use the double-backslash escape sequences, you can't use the `@` prefix to the string.

Try this:

```
const string UNCpath = "C:\\Users\\SJ\\Documents\\VS2015\\Projects\\P_01\\Debug\\EV_01.dll";

[DllImport(UNCpath,
EntryPoint = "DDentry", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern void DDentry
(
   [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.SafeArray, SafeArraySubType = VarEnum.VT_BSTR)]
    string[,] pArrayStr
);
```

Comment: Or to put it another way, if you use the `@` prefix you don't need to escape the backslashes.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use a non-constant string with an attribute and it isn't allowed. You must declare your string as "const".